# react native - get gps without internet connection

Tags: android, react-native, android-gps

My case is detect current location although no internet connection. So, is there any RN library that able to detect current GPS location without internet connection?

Answer (score -1):

It's not about modules. You need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` to *AndroidManifest.xml*. For using map in react native, you can use [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps). For getting current location you can use [Geolocation API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) and it's *getCurrentPosition* method.